# Can't tap on cell to segue until all images load

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a Table View with a load of cells with a UIImageView in each of them.

The images are loaded asynchronously from the internet and appear in the relevant cell once each image been downloaded.

The issue I'm facing is that until every image has loaded, I can't tap on a cell to segue it to another view that's linked to it.

I'm using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{[self getItemImagesAsync:urlArray];});` to start the async process that loads the images.

the `getItemImagesAsync` method is here:

```
- (void) getItemImagesAsync:(NSArray *)urlArray{

NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

ResizedImageData = imageArray;

for (NSString *searchString in urlArray) {

    if (!shouldContinueLoadingImages) {
        return;
    }

    [imageArray addObject:[self getImageFromURL:searchString]];
    ResizedImageData = imageArray;

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

}

The `shouldContinueLoadingImages` variable is set to false when the view changes (due to a search function) to stop unnecessary loading of images.

All of the image data is held in the NSArray `ResizedImageData`

So that the entire table doesn't have to wait for the images to download before rendering, the code uses a try statement in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method to see if an image exists in the image data array:

```
@try {
        cell.imageView.image = [ResizedImageData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {}
```

Is there some basic concept that I'm missing here, or is it something different?

Comment: There is no way to help you without seeing relevant code.

Comment: Fair point. It's just that I figured it would be more of a general design issue than a specific code error.

Comment: No, this is far from a general question. This is a problem specific to your code.

Comment: Fine. Relevant code added. If you need any more, just ask

Comment: One problem is that you call `reloadData` on a background thread. UI updates must be made on the main thread.

Comment: I did a test and it turns out that I added that because if I don't, the images don't update (if for example, something new is searched for) until the UIImageView goes offscreen then onscreen again. Although the issue with not being able to segue has indeed fixed itself.

Comment: My problem isn't really solved though, as this solution only leads to more problems.

Comment: Each needs to be tackled. It's mandatory that the UI be updated on the main thread. Though I would recommend that you use a whole different approach to loading images in the background. I believe the AFNetworking library has a class specifically for loading image views asynchronously. Or look at the Apple sample app LazyTableImages for an approach. Your approach has serious flaws - such as reloading the entire table for each image - that's massive overkill.

Comment: Well, I did some rejigging and I have a solution that works. I simply put `[self.tableView reloadData]` in the catch statement that I had. Now everything appears to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code has a few issues. You are reloading the data in a background thread. You are reloading the table view a lot. Each time you reload the data you throw multiple exceptions.

There is a simpler approach:

```
NSAssert([urlArray count] > indexPath.row, @"There are more rows than image URLs");
NSInteger index = indexPath.row;
NSString *URLString = [urlArray objectAtIndex:index];

// Prep the cell to download the image
cell.imageView.tag = index; // cell needs to remember which image it's downloading.
cell.imageView.image = nil; // Remove the image from the previous use of cell.

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    // Download the image in the background
    UIImage *image = [self getImageFromURL:URLString];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), 0), ^{
        // Back on the main thread, set the image in the cell.
        if (cell.imageView.tag == index) { // only if the cell is on the same index.
            cell.imageView.image = image;
        }
    });
});
```